# Overwrite WordPress plugins in child theme

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-wordpress-pages

The WordPress plugin WooCommerce allows me to overwrite any of its files by making a copy of that file and placing it in my child theme directory. This does not work for other plugins.

How does this functionality work for WooCommerce?

Why doesn't it work for other plugins?

How can I make it work for other plugins?

Comment: Hey there, have you taken any steps to solve this problem yourself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not all plugins need this functionality so it is not standard, it's just something you can allow your plugins users to do if it is relevant to its functionality / theming.

There is a great article here on how to achieve it for your own plugins, however you cannot apply this to existing plugins unless you want your copy of an existing authors work to fall out of date.

http://jeroensormani.com/how-to-add-template-files-in-your-plugin/

Answer (score 1):

#### How does this functionality work for WooCommerce?

The magic is in the coding of Woocommerce. They have added functionalities in to cater for this because of the technicality of their system and the demand for customization.

#### Why doesn't it work for other plugins?

Woocommerce have added this functionality within their development to cater for this functionality, simply said other plugins have not added this functionality to extend or customize their add-ons.

#### How can I make it work for other plugins?

The answer to this is [hooks](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/). The same way plugins "HOOK" onto wordpress, you can create a hook to do the same for the plugin. Have a search at ["custom hooks"](https://www.google.co.za/search?q=custom%20hooks%20wordpress)

Answer (score -1):

This is because WooCommerce has implemented this functionality in their plugin.
Overwriting plugins is not a Wordpress core functionnality.

You can't overwrite a custom plugin, the only way is to duplicate his content creating a new plugin, and customize this new plugin made by yourself..